# 最大値と最小値の求め方について

Tags: ruby

メソッドa,b,c,dがあり、
'a'の結果が{"symbol"=>"A", "number"=>2.0}
'b'の結果が{"symbol"=>"B", "number"=>0.3}
'c'の結果が{"symbol"=>"C", "number"=>-0.5}
'd'の結果が{"symbol"=>"D", "number"=>-1.7}
と返ってきた場合"number"の最大値と最小値を求めて結果は"symbol"で表示したいと考えています。

a~dを配列でまとめ、maxを使用したら最大値ではないものが、minを使用したら最小値ではないものが返ってきてなかなかうまくいきません。
また"number"の最大値・最小値を求め、結果はそれぞれのペアである"symbol"で表示したいと思っているのですが、やり方が全く思い浮かびません。
なにかアドバイス頂けたらありがたいです。

Comment: ソートするという方法もあるかと思います。`[a, b, c, d].sort{|x, y| x["number"] <=> y["number"]}.values_at(0, -1).map{|i| i["symbol"]}`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ソートでも上手くいきました。いろいろな方法があるんですね。勉強になります。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

メソッドの`max`、`min`にはそれぞれブロックを渡せるのでそれを利用すると解決出来そうです。

https://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/enumerable/max
https://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/enumerable/min

以下のコードで変数`max`、`min`にハッシュが入っているのであとはsymbolで出力出来るかと思います。
Ruby2.5.0で確認しました。

```
a = {"symbol"=>"A", "number"=>2.0}
b = {"symbol"=>"B", "number"=>0.3}
c = {"symbol"=>"C", "number"=>-0.5}
d = {"symbol"=>"D", "number"=>-1.7}
max = [a, b, c, d].max{|a, b| a["number"].to_f <=> b["number"].to_f}
min = [a, b, c, d].min{|a, b| a["number"].to_f <=> b["number"].to_f}
max["symbol"] # => "A"
min["symbol"] # => "D"
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみましたが思っていた通りできました。しかしminが上手くいきません。返ってきたハッシュ結果が'a'の結果が{"symbol"=>"A", "number"=>2.0}、'b'の結果が{"symbol"=>"B", "number"=>0.3}
'c'の結果が{"symbol"=>"C", "number"=>-0.5}、'd'の結果が{"symbol"=>"D", "number"=>-1.7}　だった場合、-1.7ではなく-0.5が最小値として返ってきてしまいます。何がいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: コード全体を追記していただけると何が違うのかわかるかと思います。

Comment: @gon `-0.5` や `-1.7` が実は数値でなく文字列なのでは?

Comment: 文字列だったときのためにfloat変換するように投稿を修正しました。 @gon 上記でも動きませんか？

Comment: 上手く行きました！文字列で返ってきていたみたいです。助かりました。本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: @gon よかったです！回答の承認をしていただけると助かります。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {"symbol"=>"A", "number"=>2.0}
b = {"symbol"=>"B", "number"=>0.3}
c = {"symbol"=>"C", "number"=>-0.5}
d = {"symbol"=>"D", "number"=>-1.7}

sorted_list = [a, b, c, d].sort_by{|n| n["number"]}
[sorted_list.first, sorted_list.last].map{|h| h.values}
```